# https using node/express throwing ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: html, node.js, express, web

I have been trying to figure this out for a while now, but can't find anything that helps. My server code is pretty simple

```
const path = require('path');
const https = require('https');
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const express = require('express');
const socketio = require('socket.io');
const e = require('express');
const { isObject } = require('util');
const { fstat } = require('fs');

var options = {
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./cert.pem'),
    key: fs.readFileSync('./privkey.pem'),
};

const app = express();
const server = https.createServer(options, app);
const io = socketio(server);

// Set static folder
app.use(express.static('public', { dotfiles: 'allow'}));

//app.use('/', express.static(('public', { dotfiles: 'allow'})));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 80;

server.listen(PORT, "0.0.0.0", () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));
```

I used certbot for the ssl, but when I go to my domain (works if I change to http) it throws ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE. Any idea why this is happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is process.env.PORT set? If it is not set, it will be set to port 80. However, for https, the default basic port is 443 instead of 80. [wiki/TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security)

Comment: Omg, I can't believe I missed that. I guess working on a project for an entire day with no break can be, not so good. Thanks for the help! :D